# Is "a future musician" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

I want to become a musician in the future. Is it correct to say

> I am a future musician.

I want to put it in my bio for Twitter. Are there any other better phrases?

Comment: an aspiring musician would sound more natural

Comment: @mplungjan _aspiring_ implies that the OP has already started learning music. _Future musician_, in the same vein as _future star_ is better if at the moment you have no musical knowledge but plan to start learning an instrument in the future.

Comment: Seems off-topic to me.

Comment: It reminds me ***future soldier***, and sounds a little si-fi.

Comment: Terms like _future musician_ can usually only be safely used to refer to a past state now ended. Except by prophets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Aspiring musician*** (as @mplungjan mentions in the comments) is what is used and makes sense.  It does not suggest that you have started learning music any more than you have thought about and decided that being a musician is what you want to do.  Someone who is learning music is already a musician.

Comment: I don't believe this: _Someone who is learning music is already a musician._ I studied & played the accordion, the trumpet, the flute, the electric organ, & the guitar only to discover that I was more likely to end up as a cocker spaniel or a giant cockroach than a musician.

Comment: All I'm saying is that _aspiring musician_ brings to (my) mind someone who _is_ a musician today and aspires to musical greatness rather than someone who wishes, some day, to be a musician. Can't find a dictionary that feels the same way though so I won't push the point.

Comment: Musician: "a person who plays a musical instrument".

Comment: @BillFranke, sorry to disagree with you but regardless of your degree of ability, if you can sing or play an instrument, you can call yourself a musician, IMO.  What would be *more* precise, would be for you to call yourself a lousy musician. . . though I doubt that's true! :-)

Comment: *Someone who is learning music is already a musician.* Nonsense. A singer may be learning (to read) music, but not play any instruments.  On the more general point, although your definition may (or may not) *strictly* be correct, in practice calling a person a *musician*, *painter*, *footballer*, etc. usually implies that they have reached a certain level of capability in the activity. You wouldn't call a child a 'footballer' just because he plays football in compulsory sports lessons at school.

Comment: @TrevorD - Nonsense to your "nonsense!" lol!  Someone playing sports in school is an athlete.  Given - an amateur athlete, but still an athlete!  Also, for the record, a singer doesn't need to know how to read music to be a musician - or even a professional musician.  Pavorati, it's said, did not read music but you can not argue that he was a professional opera singer with a stellar career.  What's missing is the distinction between amateur and professional (profession) and good or bad (profession).  Really, unless a certificate or degree is required, there's no reason the title can't be used.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Please read my comment more carefully: I wasn't taking about amateurs. I don't dispute that they can properly be given the appropriate 'title'. I was talking specifically about school sports or physical ed. lessons, where one is obliged to play certain games, in a very sub-amateur fashion. I had to play football at school: that doesn't make me a footballer. I had piano lessons as a child (and can still play one nursery rhyme): but that doesn't make me a pianist or a musician. My point is that there surely has to be ***some*** *basic* level of competence before using a 'title'.

Comment: Not really in terms of language - if you compete in a competition, you are a competitor - no requirement for level of competence.

Comment: @TrevorD, ok, I concede that having to take a curriculum-required 6-week module of gymnastics in high school does not give me carte blanche to call myself a "gymnast". :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing grammatically incorrect about using "future musician," but the term is [so commonly applied to babies](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22future%20musician%22&tbm=vid) that calling an adult a "future musician" sounds awkward and infantilizing.

Answer (score 1):

Because anyone who can sing or play an instrument can be considered a musician, you probably want to unambiguate your musical status for this bio:

Do you want to be a professional musician in the future?  If so, then you can say the following:

> ***"I'm an amateur musicians aspiring to go pro in the future"***
>
> or
>
> ***"It's my goal to become a professional musician in the future"***
>
> or
>
> ***"I'm studying to become a professional musician - right now I'm strictly an amateur"***

Comment: I had two girlfriends who were musicians: one piano prodigy & one violin prodigy. My college roommate was a musician: he played guitar with [Mary Travers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Travers), wrote songs, recorded albums, gave concerts. Can't sing, only [croak](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/croak). My musical abilities are limited to pushing the "Play" & "Pause" buttons on Media Player Classic. I used to pump iron but I'm not a [bodybuilder](http://www.bodybuilder-photos.com/). Been married 6 times & had many girlfriends, but I'm not a "stud", "hunk", or "fox", just a man.

Comment: @BillFranke, I get teased a lot for my philosophies but I'm eternally optimistic that a person can aspire to whatever they want to be. If selling the idea to one's subconscience by calling yourself a musician, for example, I say, go for it! :-)

Comment: Don't be fooled by self-actualization preachers who claim that we can be whatever we want to be if only we tell ourselves often enough that we can. All anyone can do is be the best **they** can be. We all have our limits. Life isn't fair & we're not all equal anywhere or ever: even postmortem some people are more important than others. One can always aspire, but one should never quit one's day job to pursue unrealizable dreams. _Rocky_ was a movie remade a million times in Hollywood; [Ali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali) was for real & a rarity.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on context.  If you want to constrain to, as you say, "I wish to be a musician in the future..."

...you have:

- A promising musician
- An aspiring musician
- A budding musician
- A potential musician
- A studying musician
- A wannabe musician
- A hopeful musician

Essentially - they all need a little more context.